# input text field resets even if cancelling submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

i have a form which onsubmit i return false to cancel the submit action
(that works fine). but the problem is that even that the submit action was canceled
the value on the text input gets erased from the input somehow...

```
search_form.onsubmit = submit_listener;
submit_listener = function(e){

    console.log(e);
    return false;
```

never had this problem before...

Comment: of what part? thats the essence

Comment: Yeah but it’s not helping. Please post more (i.e. full HTML, full JS)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved - stupid me:)

some other JS code i wrote did it....

Comment: Could you accept this answer, so it will be removed from the 'unanswered questions' list? Thanks.